# MYSQL Query issue with incorrect output

Tags: mysql

Hi all I have the following query :

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT registration, series, operator, msn, ln, model, status, pic, piccopy FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM history where status = 'active' ORDER BY date asc) AS a GROUP BY ln) a2 GROUP BY msn ORDER BY ln asc";
```

this works - Kind of.... see [here](http://www.b787register.com/airframes/stat_act.php)

its currently listing all airframes that have been or currently are active. I need it to only list CURRENTLY active airframes. This is because an airframe is scrapped or put into a museum for example - its classed as no longer active - e.g. preserved, the same for those that may be scrapped, but the above query still sees it as active. What can I do to prevent this showing aircraft that may falling into one of the following categories:

- grounded
- scrapped
- parted out
- written off
- missing
- stored
- preserved

however a grounded /stored/preserved airframe may be returned to service and become active again, so it needs to find the latest "active" and only display if its not been withdrawn after that date.

Im guessing its something simple where by it grabs the records for a certain airframe eg ET-AOP, and selects the last (latest by date aka newest date) sees if its active and if so displays it, if not then it wont. but how do I do this, its driving me mental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't have your table scheme, I've writing this as my best guess.

This is your history table:

```
history_id
plane_id 
status (active, grounded, missing etc.)
```

Selecting the planes with 'active' as latest status:

```
select plane_id from history 
 where history_id in (
  select max(history_id) from history group by plane_id
  )
 and status = 'active'
```

Comment: here is my table :  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `airframes` (
  `id` text NOT NULL,
  `msn` text NOT NULL,
  `ln` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `role` text NOT NULL,
  `test_reg` text NOT NULL,
  `built` text NOT NULL,
  `ff` text NOT NULL,
  `lf` text NOT NULL,
  `model` text NOT NULL,
  `config` text NOT NULL,
  `znum` text NOT NULL,
  `seats` text NOT NULL,
  `selcal` text NOT NULL,
  `modes` text NOT NULL,
  `engines` text NOT NULL,
  `pic` text NOT NULL,
  `location` text NOT NULL,
  `due_to` text NOT NULL,
  `piccopy` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: if you go to the website (www.b787register.com) and in the left hand column there is a search option. If you search for ET-AOP this will show you an aircraft that was built, active, in a major incident, grounded then repaired and returned to service. in this case during the period it was grounded it wouldnt show up as active in the active list as it was grounded, however when it returned to service it would again become active and be shown in the list again. I hope I made that clear?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have your table scheme, I've writing this as my best guess.

This is your history table:

history_id
plane_id 
status (active, grounded, missing etc.)
Selecting the planes with 'active' as latest status:

select plane_id from history 
 where history_id in (
  select max(history_id) from history group by plane_id
  )
 and status = 'active'